# Can my Unity Login connect with the same database as my Android Studio Login?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm making an app in Android Studio where the Login/Register authentication gets handled by a MySQL database. This app is a side product of a Unity game I'm making. In this Unity game there should be a Login screen. Can this Login screen in Unity connect to the same database and thus checks if the user exists? Does it somewhat need the same PHP code to connect to the same database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, of course, databases are external to unity or android studio, you can indeed use the same php code, but you will have to some coding on the unity part